# My Code show a different graph than other's same code when I use seaborn

Tags: python, csv, seaborn

I use this code and this is same like other's. And I use same CSV file like other's.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import seaborn as sns

train = pd.read_csv("./input/train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("./input/test.csv")

Y_train = train["label"]

# Drop 'label' column
X_train = train.drop(labels = ["label"],axis = 1) 

# free some space
del train 

g = sns.countplot(Y_train)
Y_train.value_counts()
```

And my Jupyter Notebook shows this graph:

[image: My jupyter notebook's graph]

My graph only displays a '0' label. And count is 40,000, not 4,000.

But other people's graphs are like this.

[image: other's graph]

Other's graph displays '0' to '9' labels.

This is a link where I download the CSV. [CSV download in kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/yassineghouzam/introduction-to-cnn-keras-0-997-top-6/input)

I searched for blog about `sns.coutplot`, but I couldn't find a solution because of my shallow knowledge about Seaborn.

What should I do to get a graph like other's?

Comment: whatch `Y_train` in a debugger and see if it contains all the 9 possible labels

Comment: I try without calling ```del train``` but result graph is same

Comment: Oh, I solve it. I reinstall seaborn "0.11.0" version. When I edit that question, my seaborn version was "0.12.2".

Comment: But FutureWarning message is printed. FutureWarning: Pass the following variable as a keyword arg: x. From version 0.12, the only valid positional argument will be `data`, and passing other arguments without an explicit keyword will result in an error or misinterpretation.
  warnings.warn(